# what are the options to close manual the port correctly or release the port on rhel machines?

Tags: networking, rhel, netstat, port, ss

we have redhat 7.5 server

we are suspect that port 50070 not closed correctly by the service , ( we check by netstat and PID not found ) but from the log we can see that port is in use

so we try to do the following for example ,

```
ss --kill state listening src :50070
ss: unrecognized option '--kill'
Usage: ss [ OPTIONS ]
       ss [ OPTIONS ] [ FILTER ]
   -h, --help          this message
   -V, --version       output version information
   -n, --numeric       don't resolve service names
   -r, --resolve       resolve host names
   -a, --all           display all sockets
   -l, --listening     display listening sockets
   -o, --options       show timer information
   -e, --extended      show detailed socket information
   -m, --memory        show socket memory usage
   -p, --processes     show process using socket
   -i, --info          show internal TCP information
   -s, --summary       show socket usage summary
   -b, --bpf           show bpf filter socket information
   -Z, --context       display process SELinux security contexts
   -z, --contexts      display process and socket SELinux security contexts
   -N, --net           switch to the specified network namespace name

   -4, --ipv4          display only IP version 4 sockets
   -6, --ipv6          display only IP version 6 sockets
   -0, --packet        display PACKET sockets
   -t, --tcp           display only TCP sockets
   -u, --udp           display only UDP sockets
   -d, --dccp          display only DCCP sockets
   -w, --raw           display only RAW sockets
   -x, --unix          display only Unix domain sockets
   -f, --family=FAMILY display sockets of type FAMILY

   -A, --query=QUERY, --socket=QUERY
       QUERY := {all|inet|tcp|udp|raw|unix|unix_dgram|unix_stream|unix_seqpacket|packet|netlink}[,QUERY]
```

but ss not include the kill flag

what are the option to close the port correctly or release the port on rhel machines ?

Comment: crossposted by the same user: https://serverfault.com/questions/1026236/what-are-the-options-to-close-manual-the-port-correctly-or-release-the-port-on-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't kill the port, you kill the daemon/service that opened it. You can block traffic to a port using firewalld or iptables.

First of all, try to `telnet localhost 50070`. Are you able to connect?

If yes, execute this command:

`sudo ss -tulp`
(sudo is not needed if you're executing the command as root. -p parameter shows the processes and needs elevated rights)

Locate the line mentioning port 50070. Use `grep` if you have many listening ports. The last column will show you the name and PID that has opened the port. Kill this and it should close.